# Math major as a viable degree

Tags: mathematics, graphics-programming, game-industry, hiring

While I realize there are many topics about CS vs software engineering vs game school programs, I haven't found anything relating to whether pure math degrees (with CS minor and electives) would also be a viable program. By this I mean: Would having a math major, CS minor put one at competitive disadvantage as compared to a pure CS program?

This relates specifically to game engine programming, more on the graphics side.

Background (for those who care): Currently a math major, CS minor at school and looking to land a career doing graphics engine programming. Admittedly, I love math and if at all possible would like to stay my current program as long as it doesn't put me at a competitive disadvantage trying to land a job post-graduation. That being said, I'm strong in the traditional C/C++ languages, strong concurrent programming skills, and currently produce self-made games for iOS. As an employer, how badly is the math major hurting me? Just want to get some advice from people already in the field!

Comment: If you love math, stick with what you're doing. Landing a good job is more a matter of networking and circumventing Human Resources than anything else. After a few years of experience the presence or type of degree becomes mostly irrelevant. see http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/abrash/do-what-you-love/

Comment: @DavidLively Great link! Thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with CS jobs. It doesn't really matter what your degree is in, you can still get a job, as long as you can show that you're able to code. I know plenty of very smart developers who don't have their degrees in computer science. That being said, there is still the "getting your foot in the door" part of the job, when people don't know what you can do yet, a degree is important there. **Your mathematics/CS combination seems ideal for graphics engines.** I don't think you'll have a problem getting people to take a look at your skills. Additionally, since you're strong in coding already and can show games you've produced, I think you've just sealed the deal for many employers.

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot for your response. Ya it was the "getting your foot in the door" part that I was really worried about. Really appreciate you taking the time to read/respond! Thanks!